# VUE : Vuelidate between. Using max value from store value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VUE and Vuelidate for validating form input. In this case.. It's a modal popup which gets data through ...mapGetters from the store.

If i set static values like this, it works :

```
validations: {
        refundAmount: {
            between: between(0, 40)
        }
    },
```

but when using a value from the store like this, it doesn't map against the value :

```
validations: {
        refundAmount: {
            between: between(0, this.selectedOrder ? this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0)
        }
    },
```

My hard guess... this.selectedOrder.totalprice is not existing before the vuelidate component needs it ? Not sure how to actually handle that one...

The current validation (between) accepts only from 0 to 0 (zero to zero) so clearly... the value from this.selectedOrder.totalprice is not existant...

**Here is my code :**

```js
import bus from '../global/bus.js'
import {
  mapGetters
} from "vuex"
import {
  required,
  minLength,
  between
} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

var moment = require('moment')
var alertify = require('../assets/alertify.js')

export default {
  name: "modal",
  data() {
    return {
      comment: null,
      refundAmount: null,
      paymentOptionsAgreementId: null,
      moveToAppId: null
    }
  },
  validations: {
    refundAmount: {
      between: between(0, this.selectedOrder ? this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$v.$touch()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["visibleModalComponent", "selectedOrder", "loggedInUser", "accessToken", "paymentoptions"])
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  
  <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-5">Refundér beløp</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <input
                                        v-model.trim="refundAmount" 
                                        v-on:input="$v.refundAmount.$touch" 
                                        v-bind:class="{error: $v.refundAmount.$error, 
                                                       valid: $v.refundAmount.$dirty && 
                                                       !$v.refundAmount.$invalid}"
                                        type="text" 
                                        class="form-control">
                                    </input>
                                    <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
  
</template
```

**Updated with computed value (sat correctly), but still not working :**

**Computed code :**

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["visibleModalComponent", "selectedOrder", "loggedInUser", "accessToken", "paymentoptions"]),
        totalPrice() {
            return this.selectedOrder ? this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0
        }
    },
```

**Validation :**

```
validations: {
        refundAmount: {
            between: between(0, this.totalPrice)
        }
    },
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a computed value for totalPrice.

```
export default {
  name: "modal",
  data() {
    return {
      comment: null,
      refundAmount: null,
      paymentOptionsAgreementId: null,
      moveToAppId: null
    }
  },
  validations: {
    refundAmount: {
      between: between(0, this.totalprice)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["visibleModalComponent", "selectedOrder", "loggedInUser", "accessToken", "paymentoptions"]),
    totalPrice() {
      return this.selectedOrder ? this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0
    }
  }
```

***Edit***
After collaborative effort with Terje, we have the following fix:

Vuelidate requires a function to be able to use variables as parameters to it's validations, so the working code is

```
validations: {
  refundAmount: {
    // between: between(0, this.totalPrice)
    between (value) {
      return between(0, this.totalPrice)(value)
    }
  }
},
```

Ref: [Is it possible to use a variable for validation? #55](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate/issues/55)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @richard-matsen :) I have edited the question with new code (what you suggested..) and a screenshot. The Computed value is a good idea, but still no changes in validation... Hmm.. Can you take a re-look ?

Comment: Just to re-mention... If i put between(0,50) it works perfectly.. but NOT with the computed value.

Comment: So now the question becomes, what is 'selectedOrder' when the Modal is invoked. If you could be kind enough to take a look in Vuex dev tools? If null, then need to examine the code of the parent form.

Comment: Also, screen shot shows 3 console errors showing  - are they relevant?

Comment: The 3 errors are not relevant :) Are you sure... that i dont have to use a data variable and assign that value inside the computed function ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure from the point of view of of the validation computed or data variable is the same as it's just reading it. I suggested computed in case there was delayed (async) setting of selectedOrder, but it looks like this is just coming from the parent.

Comment: How is state for selectedOrder being set prior to opening the modal? I think you need to trace the code just before opening the modal, as there seems to be nothing wrong within the modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156176/discussion-between-terje-nygard-and-richard-matsen).

Answer (score 1):

Change the Validation scheme to be dynamic as explained here https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-dynamic-validation-schema

For example, validations are usually defined like this:

```
 validations: {
        refundAmount: {
            between: between(0, this.selectedOrder ? 
               this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0)
        }
 }
```

Change validations object to a function as follows:

```
validations () { 
     return {
         refundAmount: {
             between: between(0, this.selectedOrder ?                                           
             this.selectedOrder.totalprice : 0)
         }
    }
}
```

This makes the validation schema dynamic, thereby allowing the component's data, including Vuex store data, to be accessible to built-in Vuelidate validators such as minLength, maxLength etc. , as well as custom validators using the **this** keyword.